# How to install themes with the demo content?

Tags: themes

I have an empty WordPress website: No pages, no posts, no comments.

Now I want to install themes with all the demo content as shown on the preview, but the problem is that the website is still empty! It only changes to the looks of the theme, but without content at all.

How can I install it and contain the demo data?! There is no answer to this simple question anywhere!

Answer (score 2):

That depends entirely on the theme provider. They should give you an XML file that you use to import the test data.

Or you use the [theme test content](https://github.com/WPTRT/theme-unit-test). It features some edge cases, like very long category names, and all possible formatting options, like table, `<pre>`, nested lists, and so on.

Comment: I dont get it, so if a theme provider did not add an XML file, What is the theme for?! Why do they show such a pretty preview of their theme. Also, why all the demo content is in the theme's folder in /themes/<theme_name>? How do I use that demo content without XML file? It makes no sense that the demo files ARE there, but there is no way to use them... I've already installed over 10 themes and non of them have any XML file...

Comment: Then you have to ask the theme author. I'm sure they have some guidance in their support pages.